# Coldfusion reading specific line from text file

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I want to read only line #2 from a text file, but unfortunately have found no clue how to do this. Are there any solutions besides looping and breaking when the row is found?

Comment: What is wrong with looping? There is no built-in way to extract a single line (only) from a file. You must either loop through the file OR read the entire file contents into memory and use string functions to extract a specific line number.  Both have pros and cons. However, looping with [FileReadLine](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-e-g/filereadline.html) is more robust overall than [FileRead](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-e-g/fileopen.html) and string functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step 1 - Read the file to a variable:

```
<cffile action = "read" file = "yourFile" variable = "fileContents">
```

Step 2 - Treat the variable as a chr(10) delimited list and get the second row.

```
line2 = ListGetAt(fileContents, 2, chr(10));
```

Comment: 1. The above may include extra characters depending on the o/s 2. List functions are more suitable for smaller files, as the entire file must be read into memory first. For larger files, consider using FileOpen instead.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the code that surely help to find second line of text file on windows.

```
<cfset var readTextFile = fileRead(FileName) />
<cfset var endOfFirstLine = find(chr(13) & chr(10),readTextFile) />
<cfset var FirstLine = left(readTextFile,endOfFirstLine) />
<cfset removeFirstLine= replace(#readTextFile#,#FirstLine#,"","all")>
<cfset var endOfsecondLine = find(chr(13) & chr(10),removeFirstLine) />
<!---If endOfsecondLine less than 0 means file contains only two lines--->
<cfif endOfsecondLine GT 0>
    <cfset var secoundLine = left(removeFirstLine,endOfsecondLine) />
<cfelse>
        <cfset var secoundLine = removeFirstLine/>
</cfif>

<cfoutput>#secoundLine#</cfoutput>
```

For more details see this  [FileRead](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-6d68.html), [Find](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7e7c.html), [Left](http://be.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-6e3a.html), [Replace](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7f42.html),[Chr](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-6e3b.html)

Comment: Keep in mind line separators are o/s specific. Also, while it will not cause an error, there is no need for the quotes and pound signs.

Comment: @Leigh agree string Chr(13) & Chr(10) returns a Windows newline, so this code will work for windows.